# Valid ranges for the source follower circuit, MOSFET?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I'm trying to follow the solutions for a circuits book but I'm stuck in one area. I know in order to stay in saturation \$Vgs \geq Vt\$ and \$Vds \geq Vgs - Vt\$. But, I got confused with \$Vin - Vout \geq Vt\$. Why is this true?

Comment: Because the input is at the gate and the output is at the source, so \$V_{in}-V_{out}=V_{gs}\$.

Comment: So I treat that as connected? \$V_{in} - V_{out} - V_{gs} = 0\$ Following KVL

Comment: By the way, can we write Tex code in here?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't have to use KVL to see that \$V_{in}=V_g\$ and \$V_{out}=V_s\$.

Comment: Yes, but you need to use `\$` to start and end MathJax (Tex) code, rather than just `$` like on some other SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

VDS, is the drain-source which has forward and reverse current.  When you have VDS > Vt in above threshold, the forward current dominates the reverse current is very small (<1%).  In subthreshold, we say that a device is in saturation at 100mV because the reverse current is <1% of what you see in the channel.

Here's some definitions from a class by Dr. Minch: [EKV](http://madvlsi.olin.edu/circuits/handouts/150303_EKVsummary.pdf)

That link defines saturation how pretty much everyone in low power circuits analyzes MOSFETs.